# Entities SaveChanges throws exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-3

Im saving some locations/cities in my database. Thing is everything worked fine until i added one new column to the table in the database and updated the datamodel in my project.

My locations/cities DOES get saved althrough my  `this._entities.SaveChanges();` throws an execption that goes something like:

`The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while       updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. Inner     exception message:AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key values are unique before calling AcceptChanges.`

I dont really know whats the problem since it worked before and this changes should not affect it really...

Here's some code:
First off i get all the objects into currentLocation.
I loop them through a foreach to add item to method Add().
Last i call for _entites.SaveChanges(). Everything gets saved but i get an error...

```
           var webService = new WeatherWebService();
            currentLocation = webService.FindLocation(city);

            // ...save the user in the database.
            foreach (var item in currentLocation)
            {
                this._repository.Add(item);
            }

            this._repository.Save();

    public override void Add(Location location)
    {
        this._entities.Locations.AddObject(location);
    }

    public override void Save()
    {
        this._entities.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: You'll have to post (a summary of) the classes and probably the code.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the exception may occur due to two different problems:

1- In previous calls, you have already retrieved locations; and you are trying to insert same values.
2- the primary key of location entities retrieved from web service are not unique.

In order to determine the exact problem, please check inner exceptions of the displayed exception.

Comment: Im using auto increment in the database. It gets inserted but still i get the error...Inner exception is null